# Binding element 'param' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-chartjs-2

I got the **implicitly 'any type'** with React Typescript when building a generate data function (for the chart). So, what type it should be?  My code is:

```
interface dataType {
  label: string;
  topic: {
    A: number[];
    B?: number[];
    C?: number[];
  };
}

const generateData = ({ inputData }:dataType) => {
  return {
    labels: inputData.label,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "A",
        data: inputData.topic.A,
        borderColor: "black",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
      },
      {
        label: "B",
        data: inputData.topic.B,
        borderColor: "black",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
      },
      {
        label: "C",
        data: inputData.topic.C,
       borderColor: "black",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
      },
    ],
  };
};
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Where is param in your code?

Comment: const generateData = ({ data }:dataType) => {
 
here you are trying to destructure the parameter, which is wrong. 
Replace this line with this:

const generateData = (data: dataType) => { }  

And also, it is a good practice to name interfaces, types ect... with a capital letter, like DataType.

Comment: @TusharShahi I creating the function, the data has not been set up yet, but I dont know why it yells the type error.

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan Oh, I change as you said and it works. Also, can you explain to me why? Because as usual, I destruct the props like const Func ({ prop }} but in this case it just needs const Func (prop).

Comment: Here you are passing a parameter to a function, which you are creating. We destructure(pull out) values from array or object.

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan I got it, thank you !!